# Why does Chrome requests downloads twice on iOS?

Tags: ios, node.js, google-chrome, mobile, safari

recently I’ve been running into an issue getting file downloading working on iOS. It seems like specially for Chrome/Firefox on iOS, the device requests the download route twice, once before the user clicks the ‘download’ prompt, and once again after the user presses it.  This is not a problem on Safari for iOS, and it breaks the authentication for my download routes.

I did make a demo: https://github.com/subnub/ios-chrome-download-example

You’ll notice in the demo that if you use Chrome or Firefox on iOS it requests the download route twice, not only that it will serve up all the bytes of the first request, and just discard all of them. But, if you use Safari, it will only make the download request once like it should.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, I’ve been stuck on this for some time now.

Comment: We have been seeing the same behaviour. It is causing problems for us, as we issue one-time tokens for documents to be downloaded. As the information from the first request seems to be discarded, the user is not able to download the document in Chrome for iOS. Our current theory is that this is connected to Chrome displaying the file size to the user, and that the first request is only used to read the `content-length`-header. Will update if we find the cause, or a solution.

Comment: Jumping in the comment here, have any of you guys manage to bypass the behaviour ? i'm having the same problem as I'm deleting the file after the download request.